# Updating file with sed makes characters appear at line end

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I have a properties file. I need to update few field.

```
dirParam.dprop_release_version=4.1.1
dirParam.dprop_writeToFile=true
```

So I ran the below command

```
$  sed -i -e "/dirParam\.dprop_release_version=/ s/=.*/=4\.10\.10/" -e "/dirParam\.dprop_writeToFile=/ s/=.*/=false/" file.properties
```

after update, below was what I found. It's updating...

```
^M
^M
dirParam.dprop_release_version=4.10.10
dirParam.dprop_writeToFile=false^M
^M
```

But, I could see  `"^M"` char at the end of the line.  what is this and where I am I going wrong.

Note :  Red hat linux

Comment: I suggest to use `dos2unix filename` to get rid of `^M`.

Answer (score 2):

^M is 0x0d, CARRIAGE RETURN. ([1]) You are looking at Windows-style line ends in your original file.

Unix machines use only 0x0a, LINE FEED, while Windows uses 0x0d 0x0a.

When you first looked at the file, there were *only* Windows line ends in there, and the program you used to look at the file filtered the carriage returns out for easier viewing.

But this here...

```
"/dirParam\.dprop_release_version=/ s/=.*/=4\.10\.10/"
```

...removed *everything from the `=` onward*, and that **includes** the carriage return (as your `sed` considers that to be just another byte before the line feed). You end up with a file having **mixed** line ends (most with carriage return, one without), so the program you use to look at the file *displays* the carriage returns where present (note the *absence* in the version line):

```
^M
dirParam.dprop_release_version=4.10.10
dirParam.dprop_writeToFile=false^M
```

The easiest solution is to apply `dos2unix` to the file, as @Cyrus suggested. If that is not available, `sed 's/\r$//'` will do the same.

---

[1]: Why is 0x0d displayed as `^M`? For the same reason 0x00 is displayed as `^@`... `M` is 0x4d, `@` is 0x40. (The non-displayable character plus 0x40, "escaped" by a `^`.)

Comment: Executed this command  $ sed -i -e "/dirParam\.dprop_release_version=/ s/=.*/=4\.10\.10/" -e "/dirParam\.dprop_writeToFile=/ s/=.*/=false/" file.properties

Comment: Then sed 's/\r$//' file.properties > file-temp.properties

Comment: then  mv file-temp.properties  file.properties

Comment: @BalaB: Well, did it work for you? You can also add the `"s/\r$//" to the original statement (`sed -i -e "/dirParam..." -e "s/\r$//" file.properties`) to save on one invocation and running that edit inline as well.